# OData: Query with embedded table/entity set?

Tags: odata, modeling

I have some problems modelling an OData Service. My requirement is, that I want to query an Entity Set by a list of single values and/or ranges.
Example: Give me all Entities from the Entity Set where the ID is 3, 6, 8, between 14 and 20 or between 35 and 77.

How could that be modelled? 
I thought of a Function Import, but I am not sure if a entity set (=the list of values/ranges) can be used as parameter there!?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with OData's built-in filtering mechanism, the `$filter` query string parameter.

For example, the request URI would look something like this:

`http://.../MyService.svc/EntitySet?$filter=ID eq 3 or ID eq 6 or ID eq 8 or (ID ge 14 and ID le 20) or (ID ge 35 and ID le 77)`

Comment: Simple but efficient ;-) 
Thanks!
One follow up question: Is the $filter also available for function imports or just for Entity Sets?

Comment: And one more questions: I want a query to include all Entities with ID between 1 and 40, include IDs >= 60, exclude ID 17 and exclude IDs between 99 and 105. How would that look like?

Comment: Mystery solved: $filter=((ID ge 1 and ID le 40) or ID ge 60) and ID ne 17 and not(ID ge 99 and ID le 105)